# How to fire event while Selecting using Eloquent Models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to execute some script and add some extra property to my model after selecting them from database by using:

1. `Model::find(id)`
2. `Model::where(??)->get()`
3. `Model::where(??)->first()`
4. or any other method which fetch data from
       database

Is there any way to bind an event to **selecting** from database?
Laravel has **[some events here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events)** but they are useless for me. any suggestion?

I am using Laravel 4.2

Comment: What are you intending to use these events for?

Comment: Why not use query builder?

Comment: I've used those methods inside a lot of controllers, and now need to add some property to the model after selecting instead of editing all my controllers.

Comment: I need some event for it, because when I retrieve a collection I need to store on Redis if collection not stored on Redis yet.